# How to use a twbs glyphicon in a react project

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have successfully managed to create a twbs navbar for a project that I am working on.  However, I would like to add two different glyphicons,
1) *Login* 2) *Sign Up*

The Login / Sign Up links are contained with a a twbs `NavLinkDropDown` that is labeled Contribute.

The links and dropdown look like following when rendered in the browser.
[image: contribute]

I'd like to add the following glyphicons to the project.
[image: glyphicons]

So a little googling returned [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Illizian/96867c5458c2e50c840e), which I added to my react project in order to import the glyphicons into the `navbar.js` file.

The entire [navbar.js](https://github.com/ipatch/crj-frontend/blob/master/src/components/common/navbar.js)

And the piece of the **navbar.js** that I'm modifying, but not seeing the glyphicons looks like,

```
var NavLinkDropdown = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var active = false;
    var links = this.props.links.map(function(link){
      if(link.active){
        active = true;
      }
      return (
        <NavLink key={link.text} linkTo={link.linkTo} text={link.text} active={link.active} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <li className={"dropdown " + (active ? "active" : "")}>
        <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          {this.props.text}

          <span className="caret"></span><span>{User}</span><span>{Login}</span>
        </a>
        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
          {links}
        </ul>
      </li>
    );
  }
});
```

And it presently looks like, [image: icons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably add Glyphs to these items in your App.js.

```
navbar.links = [
    {linkTo: "/about", text: "About Me"},
    {linkTo: "/contact", text: "Contact"},
    {dropdown: true, text: "Contribute", links: [
        {linkTo: "signup", text: "Sign Up", icon: User },
        {linkTo: "login", text: "Login" }
    ]}
];
```

then here in your dropdown code you could put the icon on place:

```
  return (
    <NavLink key={link.text} linkTo={link.linkTo} text={link.text} 
     active={link.active} {link.icon}/>
  );
```

I made updated button demo [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apgmYJ)

```
const User = <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-user' />

var TLink = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (this.props.icon);
    }
});

var TButton = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (<button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <TLink icon={this.props.icon}/>{this.props.name}
    </button> );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <TButton icon={User} name="Test"/>,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Comment: I just updated my question with more details, and a picture of how the icons are presently rendering on the page.